# iis installation on vista home basic

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-vista

i am a beginner at asp, i have made a website using asp.net and C#, now i want it to run  it on intranet, my laptop being server. But i can't even run the default page that is present after iis installation. I have vista home basic operating system installed on my laptop with iis 7.0.

The error i get is HTTP 404.4 page not found.

The error persists even when i try opening html pages

Please help

Comment: I think you should provide more details, what settings are you using, etc.

Comment: More info please!!! Where is this intranet? How are you accessing the page etc.

Comment: as it was not working i selected all the options that were available under that component, i really don't know much about this, do you want me write all the options i selected?

Comment: Also this sounds like a server configuration issue (as well as programming).  You may get better answers from the BOFH's at ServerFault.

Comment: Not yet tried it on an intranet. was trying to access the default page of iis 1st by using: http://localhost/iisstart.htm
for the default page which won't work either

Comment: Tell us how u access the site? is it from the laptop (server) or from another pc in the intranet? What is the address you used to access the ite .. etc.

Comment: Are you sure that iisstart.htm is there in the site?

Comment: i have already posted the string for accessing and iisstart.htm is the default page it comes after iis installation and is not a part of my site but is present in Inetpub/wwwroot folder which iis uses

Comment: then how can u access the file if its not part of the site? You cant!!

Comment: what i am saying is, after i turned on the IIS feature, there are few default htm files that are created in Inetpub/wwwroot folder, even if i try opening those files, i am unable to do so, and the files that are "definately" a part of my website and whih are present there don't open either.

Comment: but 404 is really confusing... if it is still not resolved then email me ... i can help... you post here is really not giving me any info.

Comment: i did a bit of searching myself and found that vista home basic does not actually provide the feature we are discussing, so no point, i have to make some other machine as my server.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://forums.iis.net/t/1103525.aspx) is not posible to install IIS in Home Basic.
You will need at least Home Premium to run it.

Or "upgrade" to XP :)

Comment: why is it that whenever Vista is mentioned that some snide or sarcastic remark about "downgrading" to XP is required?

Comment: When vendors offer a paid option to downgrade the operating systems, you know something is wrong with the current one. (I like and use Vista, but I acknowledge that it was flawed for most people)

Answer (score 0):

ensure that your website is pointed at the correct folder. I'd also check that the correct user accounts are able to access the files.

Comment: its not permission issue. Its page not found issue.

Comment: i am trying to open the default page, it should not give me error, as i am the administrator